# Insert data from other table and update on duplicate key

Tags: mysql

I have this query where I want to insert into table exp_channel_data data from the table homes but it inserts 7 and 8 entries and then returns the error:

> [Err] 1062 - Duplicate entry '8' for key 'PRIMARY'

This is my query (I reduced the fields to be readable):

```
INSERT INTO exp_channel_data (entry_id,site_id,channel_id,field_id_1)  SELECT 7,1,1,summary FROM homes ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE entry_id = entry_id+1
```

Comment: What are the primary and unique keys on the table?

Comment: Is `entry_id` the primary key? I think you are trying to insert a new record if one exists with the same id by incrementing the id, but of course that won't work. The `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE entry_id = entry_id+1` will change the `entry_id` of the record which is already on the table, not the one which will be inserted.

Comment: on exp_channel_data the primary is the entry_id without auto_increment and in homes the primary and auto_increment is id field. In exp_channel_data there are already some entries with entry_id = 2,3,4,5,6 that's why I start have in the select 7

Comment: @Shef How can I change the one that in going to be inserting. I want to take all the entries from homes table and insert them in exp_channel_data table

Comment: What fields does the `homes` table have?

Comment: @chchrist Sorry, I can't think of any solution right now. Frankly, I haven't faced this before. I am kind of tired, though. There must be something for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to copy all your `homes` table data into the new one:

```
INSERT INTO exp_channel_data 
    (entry_id, site_id, channel_id, field_id_1) 

  SELECT homes_id + (COALESCE(maxExp,0) + 1 - minHomes)
       , site_id, channel_id, summary 
  FROM homes AS h
    CROSS JOIN
      ( SELECT MAX(entry_id) AS maxExp
        FROM exp_channel_data
      ) AS mh
    CROSS JOIN
      ( SELECT MIN(homes_id) AS minHomes
        FROM exp_channel_data
      ) AS me
```

Comment: why do you select the homes_id?

Comment: You said you wanted to copy all data from `homes` to `exp_channel_data`